# How to retrieve a server certificate by just knowing the root CA

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I have a client application in production which make a TLS connexion to a server.

This server will get certified by a new CA in a short future (soon Amazon TrustStore service previously it was DigiCert).
For the moment it is still certified by DigiCert (`openssl s_client  -showcerts -connect ip:port` return a certificate certified by DigiCert)

Is it possible to get the futur server certificate by requested Amazon truststore "repository" if the server is already registered near Amazon TrustStore service?

Comment: Until the certificate signed by the new CA gets created what you want seems premature.

Comment: Ideally, I would have preferred to have the new certificate to be able to create a  .pem file built in advance. I use OpenSSL and need a .pem file to establish the connexion (I don't use the OS repository store for simplicity purpose... and because I don't really know how to do it in a better way) and I would like to minimize the period during which the application will not able to connect to the remote peer.

Comment: Both certificate can exist; they both can be valid;

Comment: And how can I get the second one ?

Comment: Are you the person responsible for creating the certificate used by your application?  Are you the person responsible for installing the new certificate on the server once the CA changes?

Comment: Yes to the first question. No for the second one

Comment: If you are not that person, then you do not have the ability to generate the new certificate for the application, because that CA is required to create and sign the new certificate.

Comment: But if the server certificate is already generated (I'm not sure but if it is the case), how can I get it ? That the point of my question